# Mongoose+MongoDb: For a bulk Model.create operation, how to handle validation for individual data rows?

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose

For a bulk Model.create operation, how to handle validation for individual data rows?

For example, if I am calling `Model.create(objectlist[],callback)` with an array of data, how to ensure that unique key validation for one array element does not affect the insertion of other valid array elements?

Comment: I see two ways here: validate the ids manually beforehand or not assigning IDs at all and let mongo assign ObjectIDs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate all the documents prior to the bulk `create` operation.